# How to get text over image, and is also responsive?

Tags: css, text, responsive-design

I have text over my image but it is not responsive. When it scales the text
comes over the other text.

this is my css

```
#laatstenieuws > img{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 38.4em;
float: left;
}

#laatstenieuws{
width: 50%;
float: left; 

}

#tekstnieuws{
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;

}

#tekstnieuws > h2{
color: black;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 4em;


}

#tekstnieuws > h3{
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 5em;
padding-left: 1em;

}

#tekstnieuws > p{
text-align: center;
padding-top: 3em;
padding-left: 2em;
```

}

has anyone an idea how to make is scalable?

Comment: can you put in your html too?

Comment: can we get a jfiddle to see what is happening

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8n743xpL/ It's about the text "laatste nieuws"

Comment: you mean you see the problem when you resize the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think this fixed part of it. 
https://jsfiddle.net/8n743xpL/1/

```
<div id="blogblokken" style="float: right;">
```

Comment: It's about the text "laatste nieuws" it get's over the other text when resizing the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after, but to me it looks like removing `position: absolute;` from  `#tekstnieuws` fixes things.

If not, you should add an absolute link to the image URL in the JSFiddle so we can see the image.

You may also benefit from removing the image from the HTML and adding it as a [background image](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-image/) to the div.